# How to refactor that complex singelton model method for create nested models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I have following complex method which I cut off from controller:

```
def self.create_with_company_and_employer(job_params)
  company_attributes = job_params.delete(:company_attributes)
  employer_attributes = job_params.delete(:employer_attributes)

  new(job_params) do |job|
    job.employer = Employer.find_or_create_by_email(employer_attributes)
    company_attributes[:admin_id] = job.employer.id if Company.find_by_nip(company_attributes[:nip]).nil?
    job.company = Company.find_or_create_by_nip(company_attributes)
    Employment.create(employer_id: job.employer.id, company_id: job.company.id)
  end
end
```

I using here two nested_attributes functionality for create company and employer.

Whole code you can find here: https://gist.github.com/2c3b52c35df763b6d9b4

```
company_attributes[:admin_id] = job.employer.id if Company.find_by_nip(company_attributes[:nip]).nil?
Employment.create(employer_id: job.employer.id, company_id: job.company.id)
```

Basically I would like to refactor that two lines:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your gist and i think this is a design issue.

- your Employment and Job models seem somewhat redundant, but i don't know what are their actual purpose exactly so i can't really help for now on this matter (i have a hunch that your schema could be remodeled with the employements belonging to the jobs). However, if you really want to,  you can use an `after_create` callback to manage the replication :

  ```
  class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :create_corresponding_employment

    def create_corresponding_employment
      Employment.create( employer_id: employer.id, company_id: company.id )
    end
  end
  ```

  this gets you rid of the last line of your method.
- the other line you want to get rid of is tricky : you assign an admin_id to your company, but why would you want to do that ? In fact, you're just creating a 'hidden' relation between Company and Employer (a belongs_to one). Why do you need that ? Give more information and i can help.
- one more thing: it is not advised to delete keys form the params, or even modify the hash directly. Use a copy.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. So regarding ``admin_id`` First Employer who creating ``Company`` from ``jobs#new`` form should became Administrator of that ``Company``.